# Algorithm to find "ordered combinations"

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I need an algorithm to find, what I call, "ordered combinations" (Maybe someone knows the real name for this if there is one).
Of course I already tried to come up with an algorithm on my own but I'm really stuck.

### How it should work:

Given 2 lists (not sets, order is important here!) of elements that are guaranteed to contain the same elements, all ordered combinations.
An ordered combination is a 2-tuple, 3-tuple, ... n-tuple (no limit on N) of elements that appear in the *same order in both lists*.

- Its entirely possible that an element occurs more than once in a list.
- But every element from one list is guaranteed to appear at least once in the other list.
- It does **not** matter if the output contains a combination more than once.

I'm not really sure if that makes it clear so here are multiple examples:
(List1, List2, Expected Result, Annotation)

```
ASDF
ADSF
Result: AS, AD, AF, SF, DF, ASF, ADF
```

Note: ASD is not a valid result because there is no way to have ascending indices in the second list for this combination

```
ADSD
ASDD
Result: AD, AS, AD, DD, SD, ASD, ADD
```

Note: AD appears twice because it can be created from indices 1,2 and 1,4 and in the second list 1,3 and 1,4. But it would also be correct if it only appears once. Also D appears twice in both lists in an order, so this allows ADD as a valid combination too.

```
SDFG
SDFG
Result: SD, SF, SG, DF, DG, FG, SDF, SFG, SDG, DFG, SDFG,
```

Note: Same input; all combinations are possible

```
ABCDEFG
GFEDCBA
Result: <empty>
```

Note: There are no combinations that appear in the same order in both lists

```
QWRRRRRRR
WRQ
Result: WR
```

Note: The only combination that appears in the same order in both sets is WR

### Notes:

- While it's a language agnostic algorithm I'd prefer answers that contain either C# or pseudo-code so I can understand them.
- I realized that longer combinations are always made up from shorter combinations. Example: SDF can only be a valid result if SD and DF are possible too. Maybe this helps to make the algorithm more performant by building the longer combinations from the shorter ones.
- Speed is of great importance here. This is algorithm will be used in realtime!
- If it's not clear how the algorithm works, drop a comment. I'll add an example to clarify it.
- Maybe this problem is already known and solved, but I don't know the proper name for it.

Comment: I'm not a computer scientist, but this feels non-polynomial.`WR` is  a simplification of `WR WR WR WR WR WR WR`.

Comment: For `ADSD` and `ASDD`, isn't `ASD` also possible?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Yes of course you are correct. I will edit my question to include ASD. Also ADD is possible!

Comment: Also, I suppose `SDFG` with itself is missing `DFG`? Nitpicking for sure since I'm pretty sure I understand properly.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Yes thats also a valid (and required) result

Comment: If the two strings are identical (and have no duplicate elements), the number of "ordered combinations" will be 2^n-n-1, where n is the length of the strings. Thus, the worst-case time and space requirements will inevitably be exponential. Assuming you want to use this on strings longer than, say, a few dozen elements, the tricky part will finding clever ways to do this efficiently in the special cases where the output *won't* be huge (and hoping that the other cases won't come up).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Yep, that's the idea behind [output sensitive algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Output-sensitive_algorithm). My answer is polytime plus constant time per combination (technically linear if we have to print the whole thing out).

Comment: @Felheart Your first constraint says that an element can not occur more than once in the other list, so is the example with ASDD not correct?

Comment: @Sailesh I realize that the wording on that is bad in the constraint is bad. I'll change it. The example with ASDD is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would describe this problem as enumerating common subsequences of two strings. As a first cut, make a method like this, which chooses the first letter nondeterministically and recurses (Python, sorry).

```
def commonsubseqs(word1, word2, prefix=''):
    if len(prefix) >= 2:
        print(prefix)
    for letter in set(word1) & set(word2):  # set intersection
        # figure out what's left after consuming the first instance of letter
        remainder1 = word1[word1.index(letter) + 1:]
        remainder2 = word2[word2.index(letter) + 1:]
        # take letter and recurse
        commonsubseqs(remainder1, remainder2, prefix + letter)
```

If this simple solution is not fast enough for you, then it can be improved as follows. For each pair of suffixes of the two words, we precompute the list of recursive calls. In Python again:

```
def commonsubseqshelper(table, prefix, i, j):
    if len(prefix) >= 2:
        print(''.join(prefix))
    for (letter, i1, j1) in table[i][j]:
        prefix.append(letter)
        commonsubseqshelper(table, prefix, i1, j1)
        del prefix[-1]  # delete the last item

def commonsubseqs(word1, word2):
    table = [[[(letter, word1.index(letter, i) + 1, word2.index(letter, j) + 1)
               for letter in set(word1[i:]) & set(word2[j:])]
              for j in range(len(word2) + 1)]  # 0..len(word2)
             for i in range(len(word1) + 1)]   # 0..len(word1)
    commonsubseqshelper(table, [], 0, 0)
```

This polynomial-time preprocessing step improves the speed of enumeration to its asymptotic optimum.

Comment: "which chooses the first letter nondeterministically". nondeterministically as in random? if so, why not just go through the letters in the order of list1 ?

Comment: @Felheart Nondeterministically as in go through all of the distinct possibilities.

Comment: Your described answer works really well. Could you please elaborate on the suggested improvement? I'm not sure what you mean by table? Do you mean a hashtable with letters as keys and a arrays of indices as values? How would I use them?

Comment: @Felheart I expanded the description slightly. The idea is to hoist the linear-time set intersection and find operations out of the enumeration process.

Comment: @Felheart I had a better idea for the data structures. What's left is a 2D array indexed by a position in `word1` and a position in `word2`, to a list of possible parameters for the recursive calls.

Comment: @Felheart You could even make the array 1D by precomputing the substitution from index pairs to the range of integers from 0 inclusive to `(len(word1) + 1) * (len(word2) + 1)` exclusive.